# C++11 lambda function as callback and default value

Tags: templates, c++11, lambda

I want to pass a lambda function to another function:

```
template<typename T>     
void test2(T fn){
    fn();
}

test2([]{cout<<"Hi"});
```

But I also want a default empty function in test2. So I do the next:

```
auto empty_lambda = []{};

template<typename T = decltype(empty_lambda)>
void test(T fn = empty_lambda){
    fn();
}

test();
```

And all good, but I can't put

> auto empty_lambda = []{};

inside the class, so I have to keep it in global scope.

Can I improve this somehow? Except option with `void test2(){ test2([]{}); }`

Comment: FYI, I've changed my answer: declaring a static data member with `auto` is all good, but declaring a lambda closure with `constexpr` is non-portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't *have* to be a lambda, you could [more portably use a plain-old static member function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63ecfe6c8c5c5cf5):

```
class foo {
    static void do_nothing() {}
public:
    template<typename T = decltype(do_nothing)>
    void test(T fn = do_nothing){
        fn();
    }
};
```

but if you really want lambda syntax, you can take advantage of the implicit conversion to function pointer:

```
class foo {
public:
    template<typename T = void(*)()>
    void test(T fn = []{}){
        fn();
    }
};
```

---

**RETRACTION: Original answer is non-portable, the standard does not specify that any lambda closure has a literal type so as to be usable in a constant expression.**

Believe it or not, you can use `auto` to declare a static data member (per C++11 §[dcl.spec.auto]/4):

```
class foo {
    static constexpr auto empty_lambda = []{};
public:
    template<typename T = decltype(empty_lambda)>
    void test(T fn = empty_lambda){
        fn();
    }
};

constexpr decltype(foo::empty_lambda) foo::empty_lambda;
```

The definition of the constexpr static data member is - to say the least - messy. ([Live code at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d56e4fd766a7523)).

Comment: I guess we should view it as a positive that the standard forbids that hideous keyword-soup of a syntax.

Comment: As for me - would be much better if closure have something like std::function type :) Much less headache would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`std::function`***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) like following :

```
class X
{
   static std::function<void()> f;

   template<typename T = decltype(f)>
   void test(T fn = f){
       fn();
   }
};

std::function<void()> X::f = []{};
```

See [HERE](http://ideone.com/s092Os)

Comment: Nah - std::function adds overhead when param not passed http://tinyurl.com/odjgtv8

Comment: @tower120 and this you compared with what version or code ? Anyway this is one of possible answer

Comment: compared to version in question